# How to enable SSL on my db2cli command?

Tags: ssl, db2

My database admin told me that a secure handshake of SSL credentials is required to connecting the DB2 server.

But they are not familiar with db2cli.exe.

So what is the most simple way to enable my db2cli command to initiate the connection with SSL handshake ?

Answer (score 1):

`db2cli` is a utility that's included with the IBM DB2 Data Server Driver package.  It's generally used for either validating entries in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file or registering System ODBC DSNs on Windows machines.  The `db2dsdriver.cfg` file in an XML file that actually contains all of the connection details for each database.  `db2cli` *can* be used as a debugging utility to call CLI functions, but I can't imagine too many people are using it to type CLI function calls.

So, to enable SSL, you'd either need to modify the `db2dsdriver.cfg` file to add the appropriate SSL-related options (`Security=ssl`, `SSLClientKeystoredb=/path/to/keystore`, `SSLClientKeystash=/path/to/keystash`) for the particular database.  You will also need to create the SSL client keystore/keystash and add your database server's SSL certificate to the keystore.

Alternatively, if you are defining your connections in the application you can specify these options in the DSN you pass to `SQLDriverConnect()`:

```
"Database=sampledb; Protocol=tcpip; Hostname= myhost; Servicename=50001; 
 Security=ssl; SSLClientKeystoredb=/home/test1/keystore/clientstore.kdb;
 SSLClientKeystash=/home/test1/keystore/clientstore.sth;"
```

This is [documented here.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0053518.html)

Comment: Thanks Ian.
Sounds like 1 need to generate a SHA2 key pair and place it in server / client side.
Rather than a similar handshaking protocol being done on browser's https ?